# C# Pair 2 Objects from 18 Objects With Each Other Once in 17 Row

Tags: c#, list, console-application, fixture

I'm working on a Console Application project of fixture creation but I have minor problems.I have Team class that holds the Team properties.(name etc.).Among these properties I have Rivals array which holds rivals of a teams to make sure they won't match again.(Checking from this array.)I've created 4 lists:

```
    List<Team> Home = new List<Team>(9); //Holds teams which play at Home
    List<Team> Away = new List<Team>(9); //Holds teams which play at Away

    List<Team> TempHomeList = new List<Team>(9); //Holds teams which play at home current week(purpose is swapping teams to Home to Away week to week.)
    List<Team> TempAwayList = new List<Team>(9); //Holds teams which play at away current week.
```

In the beginning,I assigned half of teams to Home List and the other half to Away List.When I try to match them,program runs until some week,but after this week which causes to crash,program only outputs that week in infinite loop with different assignments.Here are my code and screenshot:

Declarations:

```
        int counter = 0;
        int[] HomeRandomHolder = new int[Home.Count];//holds random numbers 0-8
        int[] AwayRandomHolder = new int[Away.Count];//holds random numbers 0-8
        int[] ReplayRandomHolder = new int[MatchesPerWeek];//Holds random numbers 0-8.This array will show up for assignmets which will be after 17th week.
        Competition[,] matches = new Competition[WeekNumber, MatchesPerWeek];//Competition class holds two teams which will be play with each other.
        bool found=true;//checks if altenative way of match between teams have found.
```

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < WeekNumber / 2; i++) //There will be 34 weeks and I will assign first 17 weeks.(1st week's teams will be swapped Home to Team and will be assigned to 18.week.And it will go on so far until 34.week.)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nWeek:" + i);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------");

            HomeCount = Home.Count;
            AwayCount = Away.Count;


            for (int j = 0; j < MatchesPerWeek; j++) // There will be 9 matches per week.
            {
                ReplayRandomHolderCounter = 0;
                matchCounter = 0;

                temporaryHome = Home[HomeRandomHolder[matchCounter] % HomeCount];
                temporaryAway = Away[AwayRandomHolder[matchCounter] % AwayCount];

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    if (j == 0) 
                    {
                        matches[i, j].FillCompetition(temporaryHome, temporaryAway);

                        temporaryHome.Rival[i] = temporaryAway;
                        temporaryAway.Rival[i] = temporaryHome;

                        TempHomeList.Add(temporaryHome);
                        TempAwayList.Add(temporaryAway);

                        Home.Remove(temporaryHome);
                        Away.Remove(temporaryAway);

                        HomeCount--;
                        AwayCount--;

                        matches[i + (WeekNumber / 2), ReplayRandomHolder[ReplayRandomHolderCounter]].FillCompetition(temporaryAway, temporaryHome);//FillCompetition function assigns two teams to match.
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        counter = 0;

                        while (temporaryHome.Rival.Contains(temporaryAway) && temporaryAway.Rival.Contains(temporaryHome))
                        {
                            if (counter == Away.Count)
                            {
                                j--;
                                found = false;
                                break;
                            }
                            temporaryAway = Away[counter];
                            counter++;
                        }

                        if (found)
                        {
                            matches[i, j].FillCompetition(temporaryHome, temporaryAway);

                            temporaryHome.Rival[i] = temporaryAway;
                            temporaryAway.Rival[i] = temporaryHome;


                            TempHomeList.Add(temporaryHome);
                            TempAwayList.Add(temporaryAway);

                            Home.Remove(temporaryHome);
                            Away.Remove(temporaryAway);

                            HomeCount--;
                            AwayCount--;

                            matches[i + (WeekNumber / 2), ReplayRandomHolder[ReplayRandomHolderCounter]].FillCompetition(temporaryAway, temporaryHome);
                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                {

                    if (temporaryHome.Rival.Contains(temporaryAway) && temporaryAway.Rival.Contains(temporaryHome))
                    {
                        counter = 0;

                        while (temporaryHome.Rival.Contains(temporaryAway) && temporaryAway.Rival.Contains(temporaryHome))
                        {
                            if (counter == Away.Count)
                            {
                                j--;
                                found = false;
                                break;
                            }

                            temporaryAway = Away[counter];
                            counter++;
                        }

                        if (found)
                        {
                            matches[i, j].FillCompetition(temporaryHome, temporaryAway);

                            temporaryHome.Rival[i] = temporaryAway;
                            temporaryAway.Rival[i] = temporaryHome;

                            TempHomeList.Add(temporaryHome);
                            TempAwayList.Add(temporaryAway);

                            Home.Remove(temporaryHome);
                            Away.Remove(temporaryAway);

                            HomeCount--;
                            AwayCount--;

                            matches[i + (WeekNumber / 2), ReplayRandomHolder[ReplayRandomHolderCounter]].FillCompetition(temporaryAway, temporaryHome);
                        }

                        if (!found)   //I think this part causes the error
                        {
                            j = 0;
                            i--;

                            Home.AddRange(TempHomeList);
                            Away.AddRange(TempAwayList);

                            TempHomeList.Clear();
                            TempAwayList.Clear();

                            found = true;
                            break;
                        }

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        matches[i, j].FillCompetition(temporaryHome, temporaryAway);
                        temporaryHome.Rival[i] = temporaryAway;
                        temporaryAway.Rival[i] = temporaryHome;

                        TempHomeList.Add(temporaryHome);
                        TempAwayList.Add(temporaryAway);

                        Home.Remove(temporaryHome);
                        Away.Remove(temporaryAway);

                        HomeCount--;
                        AwayCount--;


                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(temporaryHome.name + " vs " + temporaryAway.name);//Prints competition teams
            }
            ShuffleHomeAndAway(ref TempHomeList, ref TempAwayList, ref Home, ref Away); //It shuffles Home and Away per week.


        }
    }
```

The code of ShuffleHomeAndAway function:

```
public void ShuffleHomeAndAway(ref List<Team> TempHome, ref List<Team> TempAway, ref List<Team> Home, ref List<Team> Away)
    {
        Home.AddRange(TempAway);
        Away.AddRange(TempHome);

        TempHome.Clear();
        TempAway.Clear();
    }
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: From the description and the code, I still don't understand the code.

Comment: Why are you messing with i and j inside of i and j?  For sure one of those is causing the issue.  Use independent variables.  Also, put a break point in the "I think this part causes the error" block, and see if that's where the problem is... More than likely, once all distinct choices are made, it winds up decrementing forever (i or j... you do it to both, you'll need to check all loops where you're decrementing) .  So it hits that block, goes through, decrements, and then hits the loop again.

Comment: I tried it without i decrement.When the j=0,Assignments are decreasing(there must be 9 match assignments but it's less than 9.Like week 4 in screenshot.) and i is increasing which is meant to be week.I put break point to -if(!found)- and the error's source is there.What I'm trying to do is if there is no alternative way to assign teams for spesific week,then reassign these week differently until -match once- condition is provided.